# IE edge print one extra page but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've the modal window with scroll bar, while printing the modal window. I'm getting one extra blank page in IE edge.
If I use the below CSS code I'm able to get what I want it for more than one page of data,  that is if the modal have three pages of data, IE edge & chrome print exactly three pages that is perfect.  However If I have only one page of data in IE edge that's print one page data and one page blank page. 
however, this is perfectly working in Chrome (it print only one page data).
if I change to modal height to auto then it only print one page (In IE its works perfect).however if the modal has three page of data it prints only one page . Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
@media print {
 .modal {
    height: 100%;
 }
.modal-body {
    height:100%;
    overflow: visible;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Really need to see the HTML behind this, but I'm guessing the `height:100%` is pushing the page too tall in Edge and giving you that second page. You probably don't need `height:100%` in your print stylesheet. Just use `overflow:visible` or maybe `height:auto` if you need to override a specific height used elsewhere in the CSS.